# $wpdb->insert() doesnt work anymore

Tags: wpdb, wp-insert-post

I test some code from end 2016 and discover that $wpdb->insert() doesnt work anymore. **Maybe something todo with php7?** I dont know.

> Before below code did work normal. The data in $_POST() is correct filled.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_new_banner'])){    
 extract($_POST); // correct data
$wpdb->insert( 
$wpdb->prefix.'rdp_banners', 
    array( 
        'banner_id'     => $banner_id,  
        'rdp_banner'    => $rdp_banner,     
        'banner_type'   => $banner_type,            
        'customer_id'   => $customer_id,            
        'status'        => $status,             
        'company_name'  => $company_name,
        'picture'       => $picture,
        'register_date' => $register_date,
        'start_date'    => $start_date,
        'end_date'      => $end_date,   
        'price'         => $price,
        'banner_link'   => $banner_link,
    ), 
    array( '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s',) 
);
```

Do I need to change somewhere the code to make it working? Hope someone can tell me what I do wrong now.

Comment: Please elaborate on  "doesnt work anymore", any error messages in the logs? Otherwise I would avoid extract and add e.g. some validation. Make sure $wpdb isnit undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

examine below example and figure out what is wrong with your code.

```
 global $wpdb;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'employee';
    $wpdb->insert(
                    $table_name,
                    array(
                            'first_name'=>$fname,
                            'last_name'=>$lname),
                    array( '%s','%s' )
                 );
```

use `global $wpdb;`

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'rdp_banners';
$wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'banner_id'     => $banner_id,  
                'rdp_banner'    => $rdp_banner,     
                'banner_type'   => $banner_type,            
                'customer_id'   => $customer_id,            
                'status'        => $status,             
                'company_name'  => $company_name,
                'picture'       => $picture,
                'register_date' => $register_date,
                'start_date'    => $start_date,
                'end_date'      => $end_date,   
                'price'         => $price,
                'banner_link'   => $banner_link),
      array( '%d', '%d', '%d',  '%d',   '%d',   '%s',   '%s', '%s', '%s',   '%s',   '%s',   '%s')
     );
```

Comment: use this variable `global $wpdb;`

Comment: still no success with global $wpdb;

Comment: Can you show me MYSQL table fields & table name.

Comment: see above code. simple insert new record data in a table.

Comment: enable database error display via `$wpdb->show_errors()`
check what query is being formed and run via `$wpdb->last_query`

Comment: if your table name is `wp_rdp_banners` than use `$table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'rdp_banners';` otherwise remove `prefix`